# OAuth2 key/secret with github v4 graphql endpoint

Tags: github, graphql, github-api

How to pass the clientId and secret for github's graphql endpoint?

In documentation, they have shown it for rest endpoint but not sure how the new api (v4) will work with `server to server` calls.

https://developer.github.com/v3/#oauth2-keysecret

```
curl 'https://api.github.com/graphql?client_id=xxxx&client_secret=yyyy'
{
  "message": "This endpoint requires you to be authenticated.",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication"
}
```

Comment: Hey! Could you clarify whether you're using GitHub Apps or OAuth Apps? Since you mentioned "Server to Server" calls I assume you're using GitHub Apps?
https://developer.github.com/apps/differences-between-apps/

Comment: GithubApps, we want to provide a search over github api without providing users' oauth token.

Comment: Gotcha, ok! If you don't need to act on behalf of users (the default for GitHub Apps) you actually would not be using the client_id or client_secret at all. Instead, you would authenticate requests to the GraphQL API using GitHub App installation tokens: https://developer.github.com/apps/building-github-apps/authenticating-with-github-apps/#authenticating-as-an-installation